# How do I accept math operators without executing them?

Tags: python

My user must input a telephone number. My code works fine if the user enters the number in quotations, but if the user enters it without quotations then Python will calculate the number being entered using arithmetic, accepting the dashes (-) as subtraction signs. How do I fix this?

**Code**

```
str(input("enter a phone number please"))
```

**Result**

> > > enter a phone number please387-888-8992
> > >       '-9493'

**Intended Result**

```
enter a phone number please387-888-8992
>>>'387-888-8992'
```

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`raw_input()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input()`.

`input()` is the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())`; it tries to interpret all input as Python expressions. `raw_input()` simply returns the user input as a string.